# Struggling while trying to import a csv file in a rail application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, csv, ruby-on-rails-4

I am going to create an rail application to import a csv file and showing its content in webpage. Everything is working fine except one thing. If the csv file contains quoted strings such as "", ",'' then the program is not working.

My app/models/user.rb file is :-

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'csv'

  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers:true) do |row|
        User.create! row.to_hash
    end
 end
end
```

Comment: Please read this: http://railsguides.net/parse-csv-with-column-names/

Comment: my problem is not there in the link u have given @Saini

Comment: you get any error. please show

Comment: Link contain gems that auto do task for you, also use some standard software to generate csv like google sheet and excel

Comment: error  is :CSV::MalformedCSVError in UsersController#import

Comment: Illegal quoting in line 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a rescue for this error use code like this - 
may be it works for you!

```
def self.import(file)
  quote_chars = %w(" | ~ ^ & *)
  begin
     CSV.foreach(file, headers: :first_row, quote_char: quote_chars.shift) do |row|
       User.create! row.to_hash
     end
  rescue CSV::MalformedCSVError
     quote_chars.empty? ? raise : retry 
  end
end
```

Comment: it work find for you so please vote and tick the answer